# In PHP get arguments from inside a file called from outside

Tags: php, file, arguments

I got a function that calls a template file and need to check an argument specified inside the file:

*Note: Only shortened examples over here*

Inside config.php (in a class) - *Edit:* This should check if `$echo` is `true` and if it was set in a template.

```
// Edit:
function check_cb()
{
    // The {$echo} is meant to be from inside the template
    if ( $echo === TRUE AND $inside_template === TRUE )
        return $whatever = 'Using {$echo} in a callback & from inside template is not allowed.'

    return $whatever = 'Check: ok';
}
```

Inside template.php (was called before `check_cb`)

```
$echo = FALSE;
$args = array(
     'type'         => 'input'
    ,'id'           => 'input_template_UID'
    ,'label'        => 'Input Template Label'
    ,'label_sep'    => false
    ,'opt_name'     => 'abc_xyz'
    ,'value'        => 'test value'
);
example_function( $args, $echo );
```

Inside part of another class

**Question:** How can I get arguments from inside a file? Is it even possible?
**Addition:** I could also modify `example_function()`, but currently I haven't got any good ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this `include_once("template.php");` in the start of your `config.php` file.
Also add `global $echo;` inside your `check_cb()` function.

Something like this:

```
include_once("template.php");
function check_cb()
{
    global $echo;
    // The {$echo} is meant to be from inside the template
    if ( $echo === false )
        return $whatever = 'no'

    return $whatever = 'yes';
}
```

`include_once("template.php")` will basically make visible all of your functions, variables from `template.php` to `config.php`. But to use variables define outside of your function you musth use `global`keywor.

For more informations about `global` use have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) for the `include_once` statement.

Comment: You're saying I should set echo to global in every template? Btw: I updated the Q to be more clear (first function + explanation).

Comment: Oh and sorry: I wrote the Q in a way that was easy to missunderstand and had too less information - fixed with the edit.